# Scripts.Render in c# class (creating html helper). Using functions from HtmlHelper in c# file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create my own html helper. I need to add some javascript to the string I return.

```
public static string ListCheckbox(this HtmlHelper helper, string actionName, int value)
{
        return String.Format("<input type='checkbox' value='{1}' onclick='Action_{0}()'></input>", actionName, value);
}
```

How can I add this javascript, assuming that I want to keep this code in separate *.js file?

In *.cshtml file I can do it like that:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/App/markSearched.js")
```

But this doesn't work in c# file. HtmlHelper helper variable doesn't have anything like "Scripts" or "Render". Can I use those function in c# class?

Answer (score 1):

You can reuse output of `System.Web.Optimizaton.Scripts.Render` static method as following

```
using System.Web.Optimization;
 public static class CheckBoxHelper
 {
    public static MvcHtmlString ListCheckbox(this HtmlHelper helper, string actionName, int value,string jsPath)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.Append(Scripts.Render(jsPath).ToHtmlString());
        builder.AppendFormat("<input type='checkbox' value='{1}' onclick='Action_{0}()'></input>", actionName, value);
        return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
    }
  }
```

It's important to use `MvcHtmlString` as return type, or output  will be html-encoded otherwise